Is my undermount kitchen sink secured properly to the stone top?
My sink has been sinking... There is gap between the stone countertop and the sink.
This repair would be simple enough if it was just the silicone drying out, but I'm concerned the sink itself isn't secured to the countertop properly.
The only thing I see holding the sink up is some wooden blocks...
Wondering if I'm missing something, or if I need to secure it differently.
Pictures: https://imgur.com/a/UmVxbe0
I see there are a few options that don't require drilling/sawing into the counter top. Any thoughts on these?
https://a.co/d/gsc2xP0


I can't imagine that what is basically a prop drilled straight into a plywood cabinet face would ever provide the correct structure for an undermount sink.

There are many ways to attach and support an undermount sink. A "proper" or "correct" attachment is one that keeps the sink in place. In other words, the same method done well can work, but done poorly will fall after time and use. If your sink is falling, it is not properly attached.
Some methods...

Clips. Usually come with sinks designed for them, and usually attach to the sink in some kind of bracket or rail on the sink. From the photos, it looks like your sink has such a bracket. Clips are most common for top mounting, though some are designed for undermount. As you mentioned, drill/tapping a countertop may not be reliable in the long term.
Boards or blocks. Those can support the bottom of the sink, or the lip around the edge (if the sink has one — yours does not). The key is whether they are sufficiently anchored to keep the sink in place. I have used this kind of solution for a falling sink. Also key is whether they can be placed or attached so that shape of the sink will not cause them to slip.
Brackets. The ones you linked look like they could work, but that is just my conclusion from looking at the pictures there. They might also be cheap junk. If the sides of your cabinet are made from MDF (vs. plywood), screwing into that may not be strong enough in the long term. Screwing into plywood should be okay.

Consider that a gallon of water weighs a bit under ten pounds, so a full sink could easily be 50-100 lbs plus the weight of the sink itself. The attachments will have to hold that, plus any additional load from someone leaning on or dropping something into it. Compare that to standard 1-1/4" granite that is about 20lbs per square foot.
I would not expect glue alone to be enough, unless it is particularly strong and there is a lot of clean, flat surface area to spread it onto. And silicone caulk is a sealant, not an adhesive. I found these instructions for undermount clips which use epoxy glue to attach to the underside of the countertop. Note also that the epoxy/clip method is intended to be done with the sink upside-down on top of the counter (not in the installed position).

There are ways to glue an undermount sink to the bottom of a stone counter.   It takes skill and the right materials and it looks like yours was done with neither.
There are clips that attach to notches cut into the bottom of the counter. Cutting those notches also takes skill and experience but then the clips are easy DIY.
There are clips that attach to the cabinet walls but it looks like yours are a little too far away.
What you have in your question is legs.  They are easy DIY but I don't like them. They take up cabinet space and devalue your house.
You can certainly use the legs if you want, otherwise call a reputable local stone yard (ask neighbors or a neighborhood Facebook group) and ask for a labor only quote to properly attach the sink to the counter. Let them use glue or clips, their choice.
